# Single 32-bit MSI with 32/64-bit drivers

Tags: .net, com, 64-bit, wix, driver

Is it possible to include difxapp_**x86**.wixlib or difxapp_**x64**.wixlib in same [WiX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wix/) setup to install a driver in both 32-bit and 64-bit machines?

Background is that we have a setup which needs to be 32-bit regardless of the target platform (it's a .NET application which uses 32-bit COM components, so we [must build .Net assemblies as x86](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/)).

So at the end there is no difference in the MSI source files, except that 64-bit machines **require difxapp_x64.wixlib** to install the driver properly, and it seems like I still need to create two separate 32-bit MSI files for 32/64-bit platforms. Does that seem ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible: If all your components were 32-bit, you could use a single MSI. But you have x64 components (the drivers) and DifxApp uses the same ids for their 32-bit and 64-bit custom actions, so they can't both co-exist in the same .msi package.

Comment: Yes, that was the exact problem during MSI build; DifxApp actions were duplicated. I hoped that it would still be possible to do it somehow.